# Getting incorrect size (in bytes) of AES encrypted data using Python3

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, aes

I am doing the encryption of text using AES in python. 
Size of input message is **16 bytes** (128 bits). 
But when I am checking the size of encrypted data, it is showing **32 bytes**.

Size of encrypted data should be a 16 bytes.
**What is wrong in my code ?

Please help me.**

Below is the code:

```
import binascii
from os import urandom
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

def get_text_size(txt):
    return len(txt.encode('utf-8'))

def convert_byte_to_str(bt):
    return bt.decode("utf-8") 

secret_key = urandom(16)
iv = urandom(16)
obj = AES.new(secret_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

message = 'Sample test text'
print('Original message is: ', message)
print('Size of original message is: ', get_text_size(message))

encrypted_text = obj.encrypt(b'Sample test text')
print('The encrypted text', encrypted_text)
encrypted_text_size = get_text_size(convert_byte_to_str(binascii.hexlify(encrypted_text)))
print('Size of encrypted text is: ', encrypted_text_size)
```

Output of the code:

```
Original message is:  Sample test text
Size of original message is:  16

The encrypted text b'\xf1\x9f\xee\xc9\x88\xa0eg\xd1\xf3Nz\xe4\xf7-\xc7'
Size of encrypted text is:  32
```

Comment: The plaintext has a length of 16 bytes. PyCryptodome does _not_ pad implicitly, i.e. the ciphertext is as long as the plaintext. However, you hex encode the ciphertext. Thereby 1 byte is represented by 2 hex digits or 2 bytes, which doubles the length to 32 bytes. The length of the _binary_ data can be determined with `len(encrypted_text)`. Note that CBC can encrypt without padding only plaintexts whose length is an integer multiple of the block size (16 bytes for AES).

Comment: @Topaco Thank you so much for you reply. So solved by doubt.